Divide row of a Dataframe into multiple rows and columns according to the values
i was looking for some help on how to divide a single row of a df into more rows and columns in python: i have a tsv where each column can have multiple values divided by ";". Here's an example:
aapos  
552;552;552;552;566

genename  
CBSL;CBSL;CBSL;CBSL;CBSL

First thing, i want to create a row for each of these values. Then, in the columns i can have more than five values. Here's an example:
MutationTaster_model
complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae;complex_aae

MutationTaster_pred  
N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N

For these columns, i want to do a one-hot encoding for each value i can get.
Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve all of this? I know is complex problem and I apologize for that.
Thanks in advance!
Edit: as suggested, this is an example of a part of a row in the input file:
#chr    pos(1-based)    ref alt aaref   aaalt   rs_dbSNP    hg19_chr    hg19_pos(1-based)   hg18_chr    hg18_pos(1-based)   aapos   genename
21  6445558 T   G   X   C   .   21  44473990    21  43347059    552;552;552;552;566 CBSA;CBSC;CBSL;CBSO;CBSL;CSBA;CSBA;CSBA

The expected output would be something like:
#chr    pos(1-based)    ref alt aaref   aaalt   rs_dbSNP    hg19_chr    hg19_pos(1-based)   hg18_chr    hg18_pos(1-based)   aapos   CBSA CBSC CBSL CBSO CBSL CSBA CSBA CSBA
21  6445558 T   G   X   C   .   21  44473990    21  43347059    552 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
21  6445558 T   G   X   C   .   21  44473990    21  43347059    552 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
21  6445558 T   G   X   C   .   21  44473990    21  43347059    552 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
21  6445558 T   G   X   C   .   21  44473990    21  43347059    552 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
21  6445558 T   G   X   C   .   21  44473990    21  43347059    566 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

As you can see, I splitted the row into five, with each row having one aapos value and I one-hot encoded the column that didn't have five values. I want to do this for every row in my dataframe

it is hard to understand your question. It would be better if you give an example input and its corresponding expected output

How to make separate rows based on splitting a string-value:
import pandas as pd
df = df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['a;b', 'c;d'], B=['a;b;c', 'x;y;z'])) 

df.A = df.A.str.split(';')
df = df.explode("A")

This will transform
     A          B
0  a;b  a;b;c
1  c;d  x;y;z

into
   A      B
0  a  a;b;c
0  b  a;b;c
1  c  x;y;z
1  d  x;y;z

How to transform the second column into one-hot encoded categorical columns? First you again use split and explode to get B's unique values. Then one way of adding the categorical columns is to simply do a lookup
v = sorted(df.B.str.split(';').explode().unique())
# results in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']
# add the one-hot columns
for c in v:
    df["B_" + c] = df.B.str.split(';').apply(lambda lis: int(c in lis))
# B is no longer needed
df.drop(columns="B", inplace=True)

This all results in
  A  B_a  B_b  B_c  B_x  B_y  B_z
0  a    1    1    1    0    0    0
0  b    1    1    1    0    0    0
1  c    0    0    0    1    1    1
1  d    0    0    0    1    1    1

Pandas has special functions like pd.get_dummies, and pd.factorize to help create categorical values, but those are a bit akward to use here, I think. It seems simpler to just use the direct method that I showed here.
This answer above does require that there are no duplicates in the original B column (duplicates like "N;N;N"). If you do have duplicates, then you can still use similar methods, but you'll have to tweak what the new columns will be or exactly how you want to encode this (which is not at all clear to me from your question).
